# Why is ServiceSecurityContext.Current null in an MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that's using Windows authentication in the Web.config like so:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

However, if I investigate `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` from a Controller method, it's null. Shouldn't it contain the authentication info of the user since I'm using Windows authentication?

The reason I'm trying to figure this out is because I would like to know what credentials `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` is using from a Controller method. From what I gathered by reading the [MSDN article on the property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx), it uses the current security context's credentials... which is null.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The [`ServiceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx) classes is intended to be used inside WCF services. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Trying to use `ServiceContext.Current` inside an ASP.NET MVC application is like trying to use `HttpContext.Current` inside a console application => you get NULL.

> The reason I'm trying to figure this out is because I would like to
>   know what credentials CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials is
>   using from a Controller method

Then you are looking for the `User.Identity.Name` property:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I wish the MSDN article pointed to User.Identity.Name then -- all it mentions that I saw was the "current security context," which is why I was stuck on that.

Comment: Are you sure it's equal to User.Identity.Name and not WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name? I noticed that only WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name changes when using ASP.NET impersonation. User.Identity.Name is always equal to the client's username